# Wordpress on Heroku - permalinks not working even with rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, heroku

I've set up a Wordpress blog on Heroku using the great tips here - http://blog.pardner.com/2012/04/migrating-a-wordpress-blog-to-heroku/. Everything seems to be working fine with the default permalinks (http://www.mysite.com/blog/?p=123), but if I try to switch to permalinks that use the post name  - I run into problems. It seems to work fine after switching the  settings and saving them, but after a few hours (maybe when the temporary filesystem of Heroku goes away?), it stops working, and trying to access posts redirects me to my site's main page .
I implemented the changes to .htaccess as described in the above link , so my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it. Since my blog was placed at http://www.mysite.com/blog/ and not at http://www.mysite.com/,  the .htaacces file should look like this:

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```